# Is it possible to use a Variational Autoencoder as a Feature Extractor like a standard CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection, autoencoders

I have looked at autoencoders as feature extractors and I wondered if a variational autoencoder could also be used in the same way.

For standard autoencoders you would just use the encoder-network, but since the VAE has the mean and deviation in the bottleneck-layer I am not quite sure how to use the VAE as a feature extractor.

I would like to use a VAE as a feature extractor so that I can for example replace a VGG-Network for feature extraction with it. Are there any advantages/disadvantages for using different parts of the VAE as a feature extractor?

Comment: You have the choice of either using the mean and standard deviation vectors produced from the encoder as your features or else sampling from like distributions using those values.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a page where I can look at which parts to use and the advantages/disadvantages of them?

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to revise your question from asking whether it's possible to asking what the advantages/disadvantages are.